# Adding data to a row in a Dataset?

Tags: c#, dataset, row

I am trying to add data to a row in a dataset but the data is always on a new row?

I need the data to populate under its column. `I need something like Ds.Tables[0].Rows[1].add("Item")`

[image]

This is how i am inserting the data:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add("Properties");
            //GPS
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(ArrayProperties[0].FormMobiField);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ArrayProperties[0].Value);
            //Street Num and Name
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(ArrayProperties[3].FormMobiField);      
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ArrayProperties[3].Value);
            //Suburb
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(ArrayProperties[6].FormMobiField);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ArrayProperties[6].Value);
            //City
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(ArrayProperties[7].FormMobiField);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ArrayProperties[7].Value);
            //Province
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(ArrayProperties[8].FormMobiField);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ArrayProperties[8].Value);
            //Locality Map
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(ArrayProperties[9].FormMobiField);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ArrayProperties[9].Value);
            //Property Type
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(ArrayProperties[10].FormMobiField);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ArrayProperties[10].Value);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just get a new Row from the DataTable and then add that row to the table, Use [DataTable.NewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) method

```
DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr["Column1"] = "value";
dr["Column2"] = "value";
dr["Column3"] = "value";

ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
```

You are adding row after adding each column, You may first create your data table's structure by adding all the columns and then you can get the new row using `DataTable.NewRow()` and later you can add that row to your data table. After adding all the columns you may also try:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ArrayProperties[0].Value,ArrayProperties[1].Value,ArrayProperties[2].Value,ArrayProperties[3].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The columns collection of a Datatable regards the table structure. In your code you mix adding columns and populating fileds.

You should first create the structure (not tested and syntax errors can occur):

```
Dataset ds = new Dataset();
Datatable dt = new Datatable();

dt.columns.add(new Column.add(...));
...
dt.columns.add(new Column.add(...));

ds.Tables.add(dt);
```

And then:

```
Datarow r = ds.tables[0].NewRow();
r["column1"] = value1;
...
r["columnX"] = valueX;

ds.Tables[0].rows.add(r);
```

See this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Add the columns as you are adding. For populating rows, do the below.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0]) // Loop over the rows.
        {
               row[ArrayProperties[i].FormMobiField]=ArrayProperties[0].Value;
               i++;
            }
```

If it doesn't work then let me know,